# CORS Inconsistent Across three Apps

Tags: node.js, angularjs, cors

I have an analytics server ( matomo ) which is tracking nicely the main "Live" site. In turn, I have another web app "portal" which makes http calls to the analytics server successfully.
Now I'm trying to retrofit identical calls to yet another existing site. That site is where the content is created that is displayed on the Live site.
This last site is a huge nodejs + angularjs site that lives in another data center from another vendor. It successfully makes calls to a REST API layer with a different subdomain.
However, making calls to the aforementioned analytics is triggering CORS errors in the large app.
FireFox gives the following error:"(Reason: missing token ‘authorization’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel)"
I don't understand why it works on the portal but not the content-creator.
Everything is behind CloudFlare, and Cloudflare is forcing all to be https calls. 
Each app uses a subdomain of the same domain. The content-creator is successfully making calls to the api.mydomain.com. The portal is successfully making calls to the analytics.mydomain.com and api.mydomain.com.
The analytics site is using php / apache. The portal is using php/angularjs. The content provider is using nodejs / angularjs.
The live site is using nodejs / angular 2.x.
Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns-out that some headers weren't being returned. The other programs didn't care, apparently, but the third one did, even though there was no POST being done. I added the following info to the apache2 conf file:

Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"